# Is there any way to use Updates in google app for xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, monodevelop

[image: image provided on google api page]

I would like to know if there is a nuget package or if google provides this API for xamarin.forms?

I saw that it had only for kotlin and native java

reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates?hl=pt-br

Comment: Uhu, you should just use the [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to register a class from the android project. Then you can implement platform-agnostic (native) code in the android project which checks for updates

Comment: Create an interface in the xamarin.forms project / Create a class in the android project with the implementation / Register the service from the android `MainActivity` using the `DependencyService` / Use the `DependencyService` in the xamarin.forms project to resolve and call your service. It's in the link i posted

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.Core? Looks like you need at least 1.11 and the present version is 1.10.3.2. Why not request it at https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows#troubleshooting). It tells how to publish app on Google play or upload new version of apk officially.

And You can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537775/looking-up-version-and-forcing-an-update-in-xamarin), it's also about game update.

Answer (score 0):

You could review the *Play.Core* library to support app-updates:
https://github.com/PatGet/XamarinPlayCoreUpdater

If you want a example in xamarin forms, go to *PlayCoreUpdateTest/PlayCoreUpdateTest.Android* in the same repo.

I used an Android phisical device to test my app published in the store and that worked for me, good luck!